# Wagtail field change does not show up in Page Revisions

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a field on a Wagtail Page model(BlogPage) that is a m2m to a Django model(ExternalAuthor).

When this field is changed(i.e adding or removing an ExternalAuthor) to a BlogPage, this change is NOT logged in the page revision.

I'm wondering if I need to extend from something specific or somehow enable this feature somewhere for this specific field to force a log entry to the page revision?

The client would like to see this change as they have multiple people making content updates, and need to know who is adding/removing these ExternalAuthors from a BlogPage.

**Update**: This seems to not be an issue for us in a newer version of wagtail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `modelcluster.fields.ParentalManyToManyField` in place of the standard Django ManyToManyField. This handles the in-memory version of the relation that's necessary to work with Wagtail's revisions, drafts and previews.

For an example of this in use, see [the Authors relation in the Wagtail tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#authors).

Comment: Hi @gasman, thanks for your response(and all your contributions to the wagtail community). This is currently the case, where I am using `modelcluster.fields.ParentalManyToManyField`, however my Author model is not a registered snippet. 

Could this be the case for not showing in the revisions?

Comment: Closing this out due to being in the process of a major wagtail upgrade from 2.8 to 5.0. 

This seems to be working as intended in our new upgraded version thats is awaiting production push.

Thanks!